# Run nginx and php into containers with proper user for development

Tags: php, docker, nginx

I have installed and configured nginx + php-fpm on their own containers. All working fine except one thing: they're running with user `www-data` (id: 82) and same group.
So, host files, mounted to container has wrong user/group (of my primary user with 1000:1000).

How to run these containers with ability to operate with files as user 1000:1000?

Answer (score 13):

User's ID can be changed in the image to map the host user's ID for that purpose.

Example for **php-fpm-alpine**:

```
RUN apk add shadow && usermod -u 1000 www-data && groupmod -g 1000 www-data
```

As nginx runs as root (container's root and host's root) there is no need to manipulate with UIDs

Comment: After two days this was the solution! Thanks a lot!

Comment: After a week, this is the gold that I was looking for!!

Answer (score 1):

for this you have to define specific user and group in container by **docker-file**.

Dockerfile

```
FROM php:7.1.6-fpm
RUN useradd -r -m -s /usr/sbin/nologin -g username -u 1000 username

ADD start-up /usr/local/bin/start-up
RUN chmod 0777 /usr/local/bin/start-up -R
ENTRYPOINT /usr/local/bin/start-up
```

then you have to change `start-up` script for php

```
sed -i s/'user = www-data'/'user = username'/g /usr/local/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf
sed -i s/'group = www-data'/'group = username'/g /usr/local/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf
```

I use this in my project and its working.

Comment: Found easiest way for php image: `RUN apk add shadow && usermod -u 1000 www-data && groupmod -g 1000 www-data`. It for alpine based image