# Docker (compose) mounted volume not writable

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose

I am using docker compose to create an nginx-proxy and then again docker compose to attach multiple websites to it.
Everything seems to be working fine with the exception of all folders being not writable. In this example i will use a Joomla website but it happens for all of them. I am using the root user (Ubuntu Server 18.04) and the owner of the files is root. Also it seems that running 'id' both on the host machine and within the containers returns 0 which is my root user. I am baffled as to how to make it work.
So, to start, here is the proxy first:

```
docker network create nginx-proxy
```

and:

```
version: "3"
services:
  nginx-proxy:
    image: jwilder/nginx-proxy
    container_name: nginx-proxy
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro

networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: nginx-proxy
```

And for the website:

```
version: '3'

services:
  website-php-fpm:
    build:
      context: ./php-fpm
    volumes:
      - ../src:/var/www

  website-nginx:
    build:
      context: ./nginx
    volumes:
      - ../src:/var/www
      - ./nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
      - ./nginx/sites/:/etc/nginx/sites-available
      - ./nginx/conf.d/:/etc/nginx/conf.d
    depends_on:
      - website-php-fpm
    expose:
      - 80
    container_name: websitecom
    environment:
      VIRTUAL_HOST: website.com

  website-database:
    image: mysql:5.7
    volumes:
      - ../../databases/websiteDB:/var/lib/mysql
    restart: always
    environment:
      - "MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=superSecure"
      - "MYSQL_DATABASE=mydb"
      - "MYSQL_PASSWORD=mydbPass"
      - "MYSQL_USER=myDBuser"
    ports:
      - "33062:3306"

  website-phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    links:
      - website-database
    ports:
      - '8182:80'
    restart: always
    environment:
      PMA_HOST: website-database
      PMA_PORT: 3306

networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: nginx-proxy
```

The php-fpm Dockerfile:

```
FROM php:7.1.30-fpm
RUN docker-php-ext-install mysqli pdo pdo_mysql
CMD ["php-fpm"]

EXPOSE 9000
```

and the (second) nginx Dockerfile:

```
FROM nginx:alpine
RUN apk update && apk add bash
CMD ["nginx"]

EXPOSE 80 443
```

So, to sum up, my main problem is that ./src (/var/www) is unwritable although all files and folder have the correct permissions they all belong to root:root and within the containers the id command returns the same id as the host.
Please give me your insights, thanks

Comment: It's unwritable by whom? Maybe your PHP workers run as `www-data`?

Comment: @marszczybrew unwritable by PHP. I think you are onto something, i havent changed anything regarding php, so i presume they are running as www-data. Is there a way to make it run otherwise without having to change actually the files?

Comment: After two days i found the solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48718195/run-nginx-and-php-into-containers-with-proper-user-for-development

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After two days, the solution is:

```
RUN apk add shadow && usermod -u 1000 www-data && groupmod -g 1000 www-data
```

in the php Docker.