# When I run docker-compose, I got this error

Tags: docker, docker-compose, build

I have some problems.
When I run "docker-compose up -d".
I got this Error message.
please help me.

I have some problems.
When I run "docker-compose up -d".
I got this Error message.
please help me.

I have some problems.
When I run "docker-compose up -d".
I got this Error message.
please help me.

Docker file here

```
FROM php:7-fpm-alpine

ARG USERNAME=vscode
ARG USER_UID=1000
ARG USER_GID=${USER_UID}

ENV NODE_VERSION 12.13.1

#ARG USER_UID
#ARG USER_GID

# update
RUN apk upgrade --no-cache

# required libraries
RUN apk add --no-cache libzip icu freetype libwebp libpng libjpeg-turbo tzdata

# php extensions
RUN apk add --no-cache --virtual .build-deps libzip-dev icu-dev libwebp-dev libpng-dev libjpeg-turbo-dev freetype-dev $PHPIZE_DEPS && \
  pecl install -f xdebug redis && \
  docker-php-ext-enable xdebug redis && \
  docker-php-ext-configure gd \
    --with-freetype \
    # --with-png \
    --with-jpeg \
    --with-webp && \
  docker-php-ext-install -j2 bcmath intl pdo_mysql mysqli zip gd && \
  apk del -f .build-deps

# php xdebug configure
RUN echo -e "\
xdebug.remote_enable=1\n\
xdebug.remote_autostart=1\n\
xdebug.remote_connect_back=1\n\
#xdebug.remote_host=0.0.0.0\n\
xdebug.remote_port=9001\n\
#xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp\n\
#xdebug.remote_log_level=10\n\
xdebug.dump_globals=1\n\
xdebug.scream=0\n\
xdebug.show_local_vars=1\
" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini

# php composer
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer

# nodejs
RUN ARCH= && alpineArch="$(apk --print-arch)" \
      && case "${alpineArch##*-}" in \
        x86_64) \
          ARCH='x64' \
          CHECKSUM="cf493d306a6367fb7bcff5608731e1dd44b9ad8d64e7df7706916d8be0f497a1" \
          ;; \
        *) ;; \
      esac \
  && if [ -n "${CHECKSUM}" ]; then \
    set -eu; \
    curl -fsSLO --compressed "https://unofficial-builds.nodejs.org/download/release/v$NODE_VERSION/node-v$NODE_VERSION-linux-$ARCH-musl.tar.xz"; \
    echo "$CHECKSUM  node-v$NODE_VERSION-linux-$ARCH-musl.tar.xz" | sha256sum -c - \
      && tar -xJf "node-v$NODE_VERSION-linux-$ARCH-musl.tar.xz" -C /usr/local --strip-components=1 --no-same-owner \
      && ln -s /usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/bin/nodejs; \
  else \
    echo "Building from source" \
    # backup build
    && apk add --no-cache --virtual .build-deps-full \
        binutils-gold \
        g++ \
        gcc \
        gnupg \
        libgcc \
        linux-headers \
        make \
        python \
    # gpg keys listed at https://github.com/nodejs/node#release-keys
    && for key in \
      94AE36675C464D64BAFA68DD7434390BDBE9B9C5 \
      FD3A5288F042B6850C66B31F09FE44734EB7990E \
      71DCFD284A79C3B38668286BC97EC7A07EDE3FC1 \
      DD8F2338BAE7501E3DD5AC78C273792F7D83545D \
      C4F0DFFF4E8C1A8236409D08E73BC641CC11F4C8 \
      B9AE9905FFD7803F25714661B63B535A4C206CA9 \
      77984A986EBC2AA786BC0F66B01FBB92821C587A \
      8FCCA13FEF1D0C2E91008E09770F7A9A5AE15600 \
      4ED778F539E3634C779C87C6D7062848A1AB005C \
      A48C2BEE680E841632CD4E44F07496B3EB3C1762 \
      B9E2F5981AA6E0CD28160D9FF13993A75599653C \
    ; do \
      gpg --batch --keyserver hkp://p80.pool.sks-keyservers.net:80 --recv-keys "$key" || \
      gpg --batch --keyserver hkp://ipv4.pool.sks-keyservers.net --recv-keys "$key" || \
      gpg --batch --keyserver hkp://pgp.mit.edu:80 --recv-keys "$key" ; \
    done \
    && curl -fsSLO --compressed "https://nodejs.org/dist/v$NODE_VERSION/node-v$NODE_VERSION.tar.xz" \
    && curl -fsSLO --compressed "https://nodejs.org/dist/v$NODE_VERSION/SHASUMS256.txt.asc" \
    && gpg --batch --decrypt --output SHASUMS256.txt SHASUMS256.txt.asc \
    && grep " node-v$NODE_VERSION.tar.xz\$" SHASUMS256.txt | sha256sum -c - \
    && tar -xf "node-v$NODE_VERSION.tar.xz" \
    && cd "node-v$NODE_VERSION" \
    && ./configure \
    && make -j$(getconf _NPROCESSORS_ONLN) V= \
    && make install \
    && apk del .build-deps-full \
    && cd .. \
    && rm -Rf "node-v$NODE_VERSION" \
    && rm "node-v$NODE_VERSION.tar.xz" SHASUMS256.txt.asc SHASUMS256.txt; \
  fi \
  && rm -f "node-v$NODE_VERSION-linux-$ARCH-musl.tar.xz"

# change uid and gid
# https://stackoverflow.com/a/48718660/11737987
RUN apk add --no-cache --virtual .shadow-deps shadow && \
  usermod -u ${USER_UID} www-data && groupmod -g ${USER_GID} www-data && \
  apk del -f .shadow-deps

EXPOSE 9000
EXPOSE 9001
```

This is Error log here.

```
creating libtool
appending configuration tag "CXX" to libtool
configure: patching config.h.in
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating config.h
running: make
Makefile:228: warning: overriding recipe for target 'test'
Makefile:132: warning: ignoring old recipe for target 'test'
/bin/sh /tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-defaultuserdoBKpn/xdebug-3.1.1/libtool --mode=compile cc   -I. -I/tmp/pear/temp/xdebug -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-defaultuserdoBKpn/xdebug-3.1.1/include -I/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-defaultuserdoBKpn/xdebug-3.1.1/main -I/tmp/pear/temp/xdebug -I/usr/local/include/php -I/usr/local/include/php/main -I/usr/local/include/php/TSRM -I/usr/local/include/php/Zend -I/usr/local/include/php/ext -I/usr/local/include/php/ext/date/lib -I/tmp/pear/temp/xdebug/src -I/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-defaultuserdoBKpn/xdebug-3.1.1/src  -DHAVE_CONFIG_H  -g -O2   -c /tmp/pear/temp/xdebug/xdebug.c -o xdebug.lo
make: /bin/sh: Operation not permitted
make: *** [Makefile:243: xdebug.lo] Error 127
ERROR: `make' failed
The command '/bin/sh -c apk add --no-cache --virtual .build-deps libzip-dev icu-dev libwebp-dev libpng-dev libjpeg-turbo-dev freetype-dev $PHPIZE_DEPS &&   pecl install -f xdebug redis &&   docker-php-ext-enable xdebug redis &&   docker-php-ext-configure gd     --with-freetype     --with-jpeg     --with-webp &&   docker-php-ext-install -j2 bcmath intl pdo_mysql mysqli zip gd &&   apk del -f .build-deps' returned a non-zero code: 1
ERROR: Service 'php' failed to build : Build failed
```

Answer (score 0):

Oh~ I found it.
It's My server os ceonto problems.
I did "yum update" and after do "docker-compose up -d".
I have done.
haha~
Thank you everone.